# How to solve a series of equations using a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve the following series of equations and store the positive solution for each equation

Here's the code I've used:

```
s=zeros(1,100);

for i=1:100
   syms l0 positive
   eqn(i)= .0017777*(l0^.25)/(.05-l0) == i;
   s(i)=solve(eqn(i),l0);
end
```

But at the end I get the following error:

> The following error occurred converting from sym to double: Unable to
>   convert expression into double array.

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You’re trying to store the symbolic result from `solve` to a numeric vector `s`. If the result from `solve` can’t be directly converted for some value of `i` then you’ll get that error.

Comment: @horchler Is there anyway to solve this problem? Or any other way to solve this series of equations and store the solutions?

Comment: You likely don’t need to using symbolic math. Try `fzero`. But the error you’re getting may imply that the equation doesn’t have a solution for some `i`.  Print stuff out and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `1/4` power in your equation, there are complex solutions.

You only want the real solutions, so specify that...

```
solve(eqn(i),l0,'Real',true);
```

This will give you the results you want.

Note that MATLAB automatically does the conversion from the symbolic output of `solve` to a double, because you initialised `s` to be an array of doubles, not a symbolic array. You lose precision here, but can use the answer as you would any other double array.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfie. It works for this equation, but when I change the power to something like 1/25 and try `s(i)=solve((.05*(2*l0)^(1/25))/(15*(21^(1/25))*(.05-l0))==i,l0, 'real',true)`, it gives me the same error. At first I thought it might be because my equation doesn't have a real solution at all. But I tried to solve a couple of them with different `i`'s using online calculators and I got real solutions. Do you know what might be the problem here?

Comment: "using online calculators" seems flakey, did you do any analytical calculations to validate the results? Reproduce this issue with an equation for which you know the expected solution

Comment: The thing is when I write `P=.05*(2*l0)^(1/25))/(15*(21^(1/25))*(.05-l0)` and substitute for `l0` with some real values, it gives me back some real `P` which I guess means that this equation should at least have some real solutions.

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't follow from your experiment. You've shown the function has real outputs, not that the solution(s) of that function being equal to some integer `i` are real...